# using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to use an onclick

Tags: perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize-firefox

I need to be able to follow an onclick on a webpage. Here's the code I have so far.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

# Create a new instance of Mechanize
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();

# Go to page
$mech->get('http://www.website.com');

# TODO
# use a buttons onclick somehow....
```

Comment: You haven't really shown that you know what you're doing. We can't hand-hold you through this, so please give us some confidence that all you need is a hint.

Comment: I understand you can't hand hold but this is a very specific question on one line of "this", so I don't see a problem with just answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Go to page
$mech->get('http://www.google.com');

# Fill in the query box
$mech->field( q => "turtles" );

# Click the Feeling Lucky Button
$mech->click( { xpath => '//button[@name="btnI"]' } );

# Get the title of the result page
my $page_title = $mech->title();

print "$page_title\n";
```

The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) was pretty helpful in coming up with this.